# LINQ. How to use .Include for query entities with no direct connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[image]I'm trying to include in one LINQ query few entities. Entity UserPrograms > Entity Training Program > Entity SetDetails by this query

```
return await _db.UserPrograms.Include(x => x.TrainingProgram).Where(x=> x.IsPredefined.Value).AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
```

SetDetails has foreign key in TrainingPrograms, TrainingPrograms has foreign key in UserPrograms, so it look like I cannot include all of these entities to the same query. You may say that I might first get SetDetails and then join to UserPrograms+TrainingPrograms results, yes, but is it possible to make in one query?

Comment: To put it simply, `.Include(x => x.TrainingProgram.SetDetails)` includes `.Include(x => x.TrainingProgram)` and `.Include(x => x.TrainingProgram.SetDetails)` both.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, you're right. I just forgot about this option.

Comment: Please add this comment as answer.